# Integrating fd2xx.lib with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ftdi

I would love some help here, this is driving me crazy.

I'm trying to follow this tutorial. http://hackaday.com/2009/09/22/introduction-to-ftdi-bitbang-mode/

I'm using the fd2xx drivers but I don't know how to integrate everything this visual studio. I have the lib file and header file on the desktop and have linked the lib file in VS I have included the directory for the header file in the includes section. I use the code in the tutorial for the fd2xx drivers but I get 121 errors.

I have been working on this for two days and really getting stressed - I don't understand!

I know it will look ugly but here are the errors: (I have replaced the file driectories with just the file name so it's not *so* messy).

> Error 4 error C2065: 'FT_HANDLE' : undeclared identifier
>   Helloworld.cpp 20 1 helloworld
>
> Error 5 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier
>   'handle' Helloworld.cpp 20 1 helloworld
>
> Error 6 error C2065: 'handle' : undeclared identifier Helloworld.cpp
>   20 1 helloworld
>
> Error 7 error C2065: 'DWORD' : undeclared identifier Helloworld.cpp 21
>   1 helloworld
>
> Error 8 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier
>   'bytes' Helloworld.cpp 21 1 helloworld
>
> Error 9 error C2065: 'bytes' : undeclared identifier Helloworld.cpp 21
>   1 helloworld
>
> Error 10 error C3861: 'memset': identifier not found Helloworld.cpp 24
>   1 helloworld
>
> Error 11 error C3861: 'pow': identifier not found Helloworld.cpp 27 1
>   helloworld
>
> Error 12 error C3861: 'memset': identifier not found Helloworld.cpp 28
>   1 helloworld
>
> Error 13 error C3861: 'memset': identifier not found Helloworld.cpp 29
>   1 helloworld
>
> Error 14 error C2065: 'handle' : undeclared identifier Helloworld.cpp
>   44 1 helloworld
>
> Error 15 error C2065: 'FT_OK' : undeclared identifier Helloworld.cpp
>   44 1 helloworld
>
> Error 16 error C3861: 'FT_Open': identifier not found Helloworld.cpp
>   44 1 helloworld
>
> Error 17 error C2065: 'handle' : undeclared identifier Helloworld.cpp
>   48 1 helloworld
>
> Error 18 error C3861: 'FT_SetBitMode': identifier not found
>   Helloworld.cpp 48 1 helloworld
>
> Error 19 error C2065: 'handle' : undeclared identifier Helloworld.cpp
>   49 1 helloworld
>
> Error 20 error C3861: 'FT_SetBaudRate': identifier not found
>   Helloworld.cpp 49 1 helloworld
>
> Error 21 error C2065: 'handle' : undeclared identifier Helloworld.cpp
>   52 1 helloworld
>
> Error 22 error C2065: 'DWORD' : undeclared identifier Helloworld.cpp
>   52 1 helloworld
>
> Error 23 error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'sizeof'
>   Helloworld.cpp 52 1 helloworld
>
> Error 24 error C2059: syntax error : ')' Helloworld.cpp 52 1
>   helloworld
>
> 25 IntelliSense: identifier "PVOID" is undefined ftd2xx.h 59 9
>   helloworld
>
> 26 IntelliSense: identifier "ULONG" is undefined ftd2xx.h 60 9
>   helloworld
>
> 27 IntelliSense: identifier "DWORD" is undefined ftd2xx.h 172 35
>   helloworld
>
> 28 IntelliSense: identifier "DWORD" is undefined ftd2xx.h 172 41
>   helloworld
>
> 29 IntelliSense: identifier "ULONG" is undefined ftd2xx.h 189 9
>   helloworld
>
> 30 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 293 20 helloworld
>
> 31 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 299 20 helloworld
>
> 32 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 306 20 helloworld
>
> 33 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 313 20 helloworld
>
> 34 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 318 20 helloworld
>
> 35 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 326 20 helloworld
>
> 36 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 334 20 helloworld
>
> 37 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 346 20 helloworld
>
> 38 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 352 20 helloworld
>
> 39 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 358 20 helloworld
>
> 40 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 366 20 helloworld
>
> 41 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 374 20 helloworld
>
> 42 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 379 20 helloworld
>
> 43 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 384 20 helloworld
>
> 44 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 389 20 helloworld
>
> 45 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 394 20 helloworld
>
> 46 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 399 20 helloworld
>
> 47 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 405 20 helloworld
>
> 48 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 414 20 helloworld
>
> 49 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 420 20 helloworld
>
> 50 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 427 20 helloworld
>
> 51 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 433 20 helloworld
>
> 52 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 440 20 helloworld
>
> 53 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 448 20 helloworld
>
> 54 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 453 20 helloworld
>
> 55 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 458 20 helloworld
>
> 56 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 464 20 helloworld
>
> 57 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 470 20 helloworld
>
> 58 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 476 20 helloworld
>
> 59 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 483 20 helloworld
>
> 60 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 490 20 helloworld
>
> 61 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 659 20 helloworld
>
> 62 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 665 20 helloworld
>
> 63 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 675 20 helloworld
>
> 64 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 681 20 helloworld
>
> 65 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 691 20 helloworld
>
> 66 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 697 20 helloworld
>
> 67 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 704 20 helloworld
>
> 68 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 927 20 helloworld
>
> 69 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 939 20 helloworld
>
> 70 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 951 20 helloworld
>
> 71 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 957 20 helloworld
>
> 72 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 963 20 helloworld
>
> 73 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 970 20 helloworld
>
> 74 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 976 20 helloworld
>
> 75 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 983 20 helloworld
>
> 76 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 989 20 helloworld
>
> 77 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 999 20 helloworld
>
> 78 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 1004 20 helloworld
>
> 79 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 1009 20 helloworld
>
> 80 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 1015 20 helloworld
>
> 81 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 1020 20 helloworld
>
> 82 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 1030 20 helloworld
>
> 83 IntelliSense: identifier "BOOL" is undefined ftd2xx.h 1041 3
>   helloworld
>
> 84 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 1041 15 helloworld
>
> 85 IntelliSense: identifier "BOOL" is undefined ftd2xx.h 1046 3
>   helloworld
>
> 86 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 1046 15 helloworld
>
> 87 IntelliSense: identifier "BOOL" is undefined ftd2xx.h 1055 3
>   helloworld
>
> 88 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 1055 15 helloworld
>
> 89 IntelliSense: identifier "DWORD" is undefined ftd2xx.h 1064 3
>   helloworld
>
> 90 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 1064 16 helloworld
>
> 91 IntelliSense: identifier "BOOL" is undefined ftd2xx.h 1069 3
>   helloworld
>
> 92 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 1069 15 helloworld
>
> 93 IntelliSense: identifier "BOOL" is undefined ftd2xx.h 1077 3
>   helloworld
>
> 94 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 1077 15 helloworld
>
> 95 IntelliSense: identifier "BOOL" is undefined ftd2xx.h 1139 3
>   helloworld
>
> 96 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 1139 15 helloworld
>
> 97 IntelliSense: identifier "BOOL" is undefined ftd2xx.h 1144 3
>   helloworld
>
> 98 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 1144 15 helloworld
>
> 99 IntelliSense: identifier "BOOL" is undefined ftd2xx.h 1151 3
>   helloworld
>
> 100 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 1151 15 helloworld
>
> 101 IntelliSense: identifier "BOOL" is undefined ftd2xx.h 1157 3
>   helloworld
>
> 102 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 1157 15 helloworld
>
> 103 IntelliSense: identifier "BOOL" is undefined ftd2xx.h 1163 3
>   helloworld
>
> 104 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 1163 15 helloworld
>
> 105 IntelliSense: identifier "BOOL" is undefined ftd2xx.h 1169 3
>   helloworld
>
> 106 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 1169 15 helloworld
>
> 107 IntelliSense: identifier "BOOL" is undefined ftd2xx.h 1175 3
>   helloworld
>
> 108 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 1175 15 helloworld
>
> 109 IntelliSense: identifier "BOOL" is undefined ftd2xx.h 1181 3
>   helloworld
>
> 110 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 1181 15 helloworld
>
> 111 IntelliSense: identifier "BOOL" is undefined ftd2xx.h 1186 3
>   helloworld
>
> 112 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 1186 15 helloworld
>
> 113 IntelliSense: identifier "BOOL" is undefined ftd2xx.h 1192 3
>   helloworld
>
> 114 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 1192 15 helloworld
>
> 115 IntelliSense: identifier "BOOL" is undefined ftd2xx.h 1198 3
>   helloworld
>
> 116 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 1198 15 helloworld
>
> 117 IntelliSense: identifier "BOOL" is undefined ftd2xx.h 1204 3
>   helloworld
>
> 118 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 1204 15 helloworld
>
> 119 IntelliSense: identifier "BOOL" is undefined ftd2xx.h 1210 3
>   helloworld
>
> 120 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 1210 15 helloworld
>
> 121 IntelliSense: identifier "BOOL" is undefined ftd2xx.h 1217 3
>   helloworld
>
> 122 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 1217 15 helloworld
>
> 123 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 1246 20 helloworld
>
> 124 IntelliSense: expected a ';' ftd2xx.h 1251 20 helloworld

Comment: I don't know the specifics of the FTDI libraries, but in case it helps here's a working Visual Studio project for an FTDI-based hardware random number generator: https://github.com/waywardgeek/infnoise/tree/master/software

Comment: You are using completely wrong header file.  ftd2xx.h should only be used when you create your own device driver that uses the FTDI chip.  You need to use ftdi.h, just like the web page shows.

Comment: I'm using the ftdi driver. The sample code for ftd2xx.h is below the first.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for your replies. It turns out that the example would never have worked with the application note I was following. I ended up contacting FTDI directly, they responded very quickly with a new proof application note that worked flawlessly very easily. They have asked me not to share the document, if you want it look out for it on their website I think it should be there soon.